# How to vectorize computation of mean over specific set of indices given as matrix rows?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, pytorch

I have a problem vectorizing some code in pytorch. 
A numpy solution would also help, but a pytorch solution would be better.
I'm going to use `array` and `Tensor` interchangeably.

The problem I am facing is this:

Given an 2D float array `X` of size (n, x), and a boolean 2D array `A` of size (n, n), compute the mean over rows in `X` indexed by rows in `A`. 
The problem is that the rows in `A` contain a variable number of `True` indices.

Example (numpy):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
X = np.arange(6 * 3, dtype=np.float32).reshape(6, 3)

# Compute the mean in numpy with a for loop
means_np = np.array([X[A.astype(np.bool)[i]].mean(axis=0) for i in np.arange(len(A)])
```

So this examples works, but this formulation has 3 problems:

1. The for loop is slow for larger `A` and `X`. I need to loop over a few 10 thousand indices.
2. It can happen that `A[i]` contains no `True` indices. This results in `np.mean(np.array([]))`, which is `NaN`. I want this to be 0 instead.
3. Implementing it this way in pytorch results in SIGFPE (Floating point error) during the backwards pass of backpropagation through this function. The cause is when nothing being selected.

The workaround that I am using now is (also see code below):

- Set the diagonal elements of `A` to `True` so that there is always at least one element to select
- sum of all selected elements, subtract the values in `X` from that sum (the diagonal is guaranteed to be `False` in the beginning), and divide by the number of `True` elements - 1 clamped to at least 1 in each row.

This works, is differentiable in pytorch and does not produce `NaN`, but I still need a loop over all indices. 
How can I get rid of this loop?

This is my current pytorch code:

```
 import torch
 A = torch.from_numpy(A).bytes()
 X = torch.from_numpy(X)
 A[np.diag_indices(len(A)] = 1  # Set the diagonal to 1
 means = [(X[A[i]].sum(dim=0) - X[i]) / torch.clamp(A[i].sum() - 1, min=1.)  # Compute the mean safely
          for i in range(len(A))]  # Get rid of the loop somehow
 means = torch.stack(means)
```

I don't mind if your version looks completely different, as long as it is differentiable and produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage `matrix-multiplication` -

```
c = A.sum(1,keepdims=True)
means_np = np.where(c==0,0,A.dot(X)/c)
```

We can optimize it further by converting `A` to `float32` dtype if it's not already so and if the loss of precision is okay there, as shown below -

```
In [57]: np.random.seed(0)

In [58]: A = np.random.randint(0,2,(1000,1000))

In [59]: X = np.random.rand(1000,1000).astype(np.float32)

In [60]: %timeit A.dot(X)
10 loops, best of 3: 27 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit A.astype(np.float32).dot(X)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.2 ms per loop

In [62]: np.allclose(A.dot(X), A.astype(np.float32).dot(X))
Out[62]: True
```

Thus, use `A.astype(np.float32).dot(X)` to replace `A.dot(X)`.

Alternatively, to solve for the case where the row-sum is `zero`, and that requires us to use `np.where`, we could assign any non-zero value, say `1` into `c` and then simply divide by it, like so -

```
c = A.sum(1,keepdims=True)
c[c==0] = 1
means_np = A.dot(X)/c
```

This would also avoid the warning that we would otherwise get from `np.where` in those zero row sum cases.

Comment: Nice! Conversion to pytorch is easy: rename `keepdims` to `keepdim`, replace functions with torch equivalents and `torch.where` requires `torch.Tensor([0])` instead of a scalar 0.

Comment: The count assignment is mandatory if gradients are needed. Otherwise the backwards update will produce NaN due to division by zero. dividing `torch.clamp(counts, min=1.)` works